Calculate the Integral $\iint x^{2}\:dydz + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )\:dx dy$
The integral that I need to calculate is the integral of the second kind:
$$I=\iint_{S} x^{2}\:dydz + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )\:dx dy$$
with $S$ being the boundary of the following object: $x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq 1$. I have not so much experience with multivariable calculus, so I am not so familiar with the notation. I figured (allegedly) that it is surface integral, and the region would be something like
$$0\leq x^{2}+y^{2}\leq z\leq 1\implies \begin{cases}
-1\leq x\leq 1 \\
-1\leq y\leq 1 \\
0\leq z\leq 1
\end{cases}$$
Integrating the function itself is easy but the integral is what I do not know how to solve. Can someone help me with this? I believe that I understood the problem wrong.
For those that want to close the question because of the lack of detail, that thing is the entire statement of the problem. Nothing else. And I am being thrown off because there's someone who also said that I have to instead solve the problem as
$$I=\iint_{S} x^{2}\:dydz + \iint_{R} (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )\:dx dy$$ for another object $R$
Attempt 1
Alright, let's try it again. For this problem, I think the surface would be $$x^{2}+y^{2}=z, 0\leq z\leq 1$$
This means that we can parameterize it as:
$$r(v,u)=(v\cos{(u)}, v\sin{(u)}, v): \begin{cases}
0\leq u\leq 2\pi \\
0\leq v\leq 1
\end{cases}$$
The integral is seems to be denoted in differential form, which is $$I=\iint_{S} x^{2}\:dy\wedge dz + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )\:dx\wedge dy$$
As provided by Kurt. G. Then, we can obtain the vector field $F=(x^{2},0,x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})$.
Then, I can calculate the surface integral now using: $$\iint_{S}Fdx \land dy + G dy\land dz+Hdz\land dx=\iint_{D}\left[ F \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} + G\frac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial (u,v)}+\frac{\partial(z,x)}{\partial (u,v)} \right] dudv$$
Am I right?
Attempt 2
Okay, I was dumb. Now, the parameterization is wrong.
if $(x,y)=v\cos(u),v\sin{(u)}$, then $z=v^{2}$. Hence, instead, we have...
$$r(u,v)=(v\cos{(u)},v\sin{(u)},v^{2}),\begin{cases}
0\leq u\leq 2\pi \\
-1\leq v \leq 1
\end{cases}$$
Theoretical Concepts
Since I want a bit of mind toward the theoretical base that I am working on, I'll just leave it here.
Let $S$ be a smooth parameterized surface:
$$\begin{cases}
x=f(u,v) \\
y = g(u,v) \\
z = h(u,v) \\
(u,v)\in D
\end{cases}$$
with orientation corresponding to the ordering $u,v$. Then, we have $$dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv$$
Similarly, $$dy=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv$$
Hence, $$\begin{split}
dx\land dy & = \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv \right)\land\left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv \right)\\ 
& = \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}- \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \right) du \land dv
\\& =\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}du\land dv
\end{split}$$
Working all the same, we got
$$\begin{align}
dx\land dy = \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}- \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \right) du \land dv
 =\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}du\land dv \\
dy\land dz = \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}- \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \right) du \land dv
 =\frac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial(u,v)}du\land dv \\
dz\land dx = \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}- \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \right) du \land dv
 =\frac{\partial(z,x)}{\partial(u,v)}du\land dv
\end{align}$$
Then, we can use $$\iint_{S}Fdx \land dy + G dy\land dz+Hdz\land dx=\iint_{D}\left[ F \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} + G\frac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial (u,v)}+\frac{\partial(z,x)}{\partial (u,v)} \right] dudv$$
which is guaranteed by Stoke's theorem.

Working out the whole thing is a problem, since it's quite long. Still, writing everything in order as
$$I=\iint_{S} (x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} )\:dx \land dy +x^{2}\:dy\land dz$$
For the first term, converting to the new coordinate $(u,v)$: $$\begin{cases}
r_{1}=v^{2}\cos^{2}{(u)}+v^{2}\sin^{2}{(u)}+(v^{2})^{2}=v^{2}(1+v^{2})\\
r_{2}=v^{2}\cos^{2}{(u)}
\end{cases}
$$
For a vector field $F(r_{1},r_{2},0)$. I think I will be able to solve this more, but it is quite long, and after this it is kind of trivial, so if I am right, this is the path of solution.

The object described by the inequalities is a volume, not a surface. You can try to approach the problem by treating $S$ as the boundary of said volume, $\partial V$. How many different (smooth) surfaces does it take to enclose tha volume?

It seems to me that for $S$ I would need to rewrite the boundary as $-1\leq x \leq z$, $-1\leq y \leq z$, $0 \leq z\leq 1$ of which then would look like... a stack of circles with radius from $0\to 1$, which looks like a regular quadratic funnel?

If $S$ is the "object" $x^2 + y^2 \leq z \leq 1$ it is not a two-dimensional surface. Then the entire problem statement (first formula in OP) is nonsense.

I updated the "object" as being the boundary of such object instead.

Then the exercise is more correctly written as $$I=\iint_{S} x^{2}:dy\wedge dz + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ):dx\wedge dy,.$$ There is a standard literature on such surface integrals. We won't give the introduction to that subject here. Make the relevant attempts and let us know when/where you get stuck.

@KurtG. I added my first attempt after your suggestion. I still feel that there's something I misunderstood.

The parameterization for the paraboloid is not quite right. If $(x,y)=(v\cos u, v\sin u)$, then $z=x^2+y^2=v^2\neq v$.

Quite meager that attempt. The integral gives a numerical result. What do you get?

@user170231 thank you very much for the correction, I fixed it.

The boundary $S$ of $x^2+y^2\le z\le 1$ consists of two parts: the paraboloid plus a disk of radius one that caps it at $z=1,.$ So far your attempts only deal with the paraboloid. Spoiler: the result is $2\pi/3,.$

(I have assumed that the capping disk has the opposite orientation than the paraboloid. In other words: all normal vectors to the surface point outwards.)

Oh I see, I only look at the surrounding paraboloid and forgot about the total boundary of the object. If possible, can you have the solution up? Thanks for your help, too.

I do in fact have the complete solution that we can use later to check. You will learn more when you try as much yourself rather than passively consuming someone else's solution. Your last paragraph looks promising. What are the explicit expressions ("pullbacks") of $dx\wedge dy$ and $dy\wedge dz$ in terms of $du$ and $dv,?$ You should figure that out now.

Alright, I wll try within due time.
